# Dynamically changing menus in Vue storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an application menu in the store, I want to draw it based on the user's roles (I get it with a token) by changing the value of the isShow indicator to true

```
export const state = () => ({
    default: [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: "menuitems.admin.frp",
        link: "/dictionary/fprUser",
        icon: "ri-profile-line",
        isShow: false,
        role: ["admin"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        label: "menuitems.navigation.text",
        isTitle: true,
        isShow: false,
        role: ["admin", "engineer"]
    },
    ....
    ]
});
export const getters = {
    getMenu(state) {
        return state.default;
    }
};
export const mutations = {
    SET_IS_SHOW(state, playload) {
    console.log(playload);
    }
};
export const actions = {
    storeSetMenuIsShow({ commit }, { elementId, bool }) {
    commit("SET_IS_SHOW", { elementId, bool });
    }
};
```

in component if i use dispatch - console.log(playload) work in fine

```
this.$store.dispatch("menu/storeSetMenuIsShow", {
      elementId: 1,
      bool: true
    });
```

result

```
{ elementId: 1, bool: true }
```

in SideBar.vue

load data

```
data() {
    return {
      menuItems: this.$store.state.menu.default,
      user: {
        role: null
      }
    };
  },
```

If the user has at least 1 role, the menu item must be specified
I can iterate over the list locally, and display a menu, depending on whether the user has one role or a number of roles.

```
methods: {
    decodeToken(token) {
      var decoded = this.$jwt.decode(token);
      this.user.role =
        decoded["http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"];
      if (this.user.role == null) {
        return;
      }

      if (typeof this.user.role == "string") {
        // this.$store.dispatch("menu/storeSetMenuIsShow", {
        //   elementId: 1,
        //   bool: true
        // });
        this.menuItems.forEach(element => {
          if (element.role.indexOf(this.user.role) !== -1) {
            // element.id = 1; 
            element.isShow = true;
          }
        });
        return;
      }
      if (typeof this.user.role == "object") {
        this.menuItems.forEach(element => {
          this.user.role.forEach(role => {
            if (element.role.indexOf(role)) {
              // element.id = 1;
              element.isShow = true;
            }
          });
        });
        return;
      }
    },
 //....
 }
```

But of course I get an error saying that I am changing the repository without using mutations

```
Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

How can this be done, given that I can already send multiple parameters (ElementId and true / false) to VueStore?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the method this way and just pass an object, since for that mutation the boolean is always true:

```
  if (typeof this.user.role == "string") {
    // this.$store.dispatch("menu/storeSetMenuIsShow", {
    //   elementId: 1,
    //   bool: true
    // });
    this.menuItems.forEach(element => {
      if (element.role.indexOf(this.user.role) !== -1) {
        var menuItem = Object.assign({}, element)
        menuItem.isShow = true
        this.$store.commit('menu/SET_IS_SHOW', menuItem)
      }
    });
    return;
  }
  if (typeof this.user.role == "object") {
    this.menuItems.forEach(element => {
      this.user.role.forEach(role => {
        if (element.role.indexOf(role)) {
        var menuItem = Object.assign({}, element)
        menuItem.isShow = true
        this.$store.commit('menu/SET_IS_SHOW', menuItem)
        }
      });
    });
    return;
  }
```

And your mutation:

```
SET_IS_SHOW(state, payload) {
  var index = state.default.findIndex(x => x.id === payload.id)
  Vue.set(state.default, index, payload)
}
```

If you haven't yet, add in your store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Comment: You cannot address mutation directly, you need to use actions - it is correct? - Error: payload is not defined

Comment: and [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Comment: You can commit mutation directly

Comment: place console.log(element) above the line where committing the mutation and see result.

Comment: You can commit mutation directly - 
I know about this, but according to the documentation it is indicated - use for this action

Comment: Usually you use action if it's involved an API call. In this case is not..

Comment: if the user logs in under the role engener and some other role (there is no administrator) - the administrator menu is still drawn for him